# Fetching transaction count from Hyperledger Fabric's metrics in Angular using APIs: How can I do it?

Tags: angular, rest, hyperledger-fabric

Is there any apis provided by **Hyperledger fabric** for the metrics. **link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/metrics_reference.html**

I need to use some of these metrics and find number of transactions in an anuglar application, for that i need apis for these metrics.

api calls provided by Hyperledger